# select user with more than one category

Tags: mysql, sql

now here I have these tables, user can have more than category, and I want to show table like this

I've wrote this statement but It repeats user name with every category

```
SELECT 
  c.name
FROM 
  permission p
  JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = p.user_id
  JOIN category c
    ON c.id = p.category_id
```

USER DATA TABLE // this table is what I want to get because every user have more than one category

| username | email | categories |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row | row | math, science |
| row | row | row, row, row |

//those tables are what I have in the database

USERS TABLE

| USER ID | username | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | row | row |
| 6 | row | row |

CATEGORY TABLE

| C ID | C NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | math |
| 9 | science |

PERMISSION TABLE

| ID | USER ID | C ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 2 | 6 | 9 |

Answer (score 0):

If you have only username use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.name
FROM
    permission p
        JOIN
    users u ON u.id = p.user_id
        JOIN
    category c ON c.id = p.category_id
```

With more columns you should [look](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) for `GROUP BY c.name`

Answer (score 0):

As user info in users table is unique so max keyword is used for optimization purpose. If same category is mapped multiple times with single user then use DISTINCT keyword inside GROUP_CONCAT functions. GROUP_CONCAT() is build in function for MySQL.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT MAX(u.username) username
     , MAX(u.email) email
     , GROUP_CONCAT(c.cname) categories
FROM users u
INNER JOIN permission p
        ON u.userid = p.userid
INNER JOIN category c
        ON c.cid = p.cid
GROUP BY u.UserID;
```